# Return from function on promise rejection

Tags: node.js, promise

I have two functions. One called something, and another that gets called from it, asyncfunc. My issue is that if inside the asyncfunc, function an error gets thrown I want to stop executing the rest of the function and return. I found out I can get that behavior if I re-throw the error inside the catch, but I need to add another catch afterwards.

So how can I return from the function if any of the promises get rejected ? (In this specific case they are one after the other so I guess I can use .then, but I want the same result if they are not nested).

```
async function something()
{
    await asyncfunc().catch(e => console.error(e));
}

async function asyncfunc()
{
    await some_promise.catch(err => { throw new Error(err) }); // Error gets swallowed unless I add another catch

    await some_promise2.catch(err => { throw new Error(err) }); // Error gets thrown here, return and don't execute promise 3

    var data = await some_promise3.catch(err => { throw new Error(err) });

    return data;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can catch your error in `something()` function and your `asyncFunc` can be chained to propagate error when thrown:

```
function something()
{
    // You dont need to call async/await, if you are not returning 
    // and this function only has one call.
    asyncfunc().catch(e => console.error(e));
}

// Notice I have removed "async"
function asyncfunc()
{
    // its a simple case of chain of Promises.
    // to execute it serially you can chain it like this;

    return some_promise
         .then(some_promise2)
         .then(some_promise3)
         .catch(error => {
             // you can do something like 'log' it
             throw error;
         })
}
```